# Why am i getting a System.NullReferenceException error in my code?

Tags: c#, winforms, nullreferenceexception

I'm currently working on an exercise for my c# class. I am having some trouble with one particular part and would really appreciate some help.

I am working on an exercise in which we are given an incomplete project file.

The project has multiple classes, this class is for controlling squares that are placed on the board.

```
namespace HareAndTortoise {
public partial class SquareControl : PictureBox {

    public const int SQUARE_SIZE = 100;

    private Square square;  // A reference to the corresponding square object

    private BindingList<Player> players;  // References the players in the overall game.

    private bool[] containsPlayers = new bool[6];//HareAndTortoiseGame.MAX_PLAYERS];
    public bool[] ContainsPlayers {
        get {
            return containsPlayers;
        }
        set {
            containsPlayers = value;
        }
    }



    // Font and brush for displaying text inside the square.
    private Font textFont = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8);
    private Brush textBrush = Brushes.White;

    public SquareControl(Square square, BindingList<Player> players) {

        this.square  = square;
        this.players = players;

        //  Set GUI properties of the whole square.
        Size = new Size(SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE);
        Margin = new Padding(0);  // No spacing around the cell. (Default is 3 pixels.)
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;

        SetImageWhenNeeded();
    }

    private void SetImageWhenNeeded()
    {

        if (square is Square.Win_Square)
        {
            LoadImageFromFile("Win.png");
            textBrush = Brushes.Black;
        }
        else if (square is Square.Lose_Square)
        {
            LoadImageFromFile("Lose.png");
            textBrush = Brushes.Red;
        }
        else if (square is Square.Chance_Square)
        {
            LoadImageFromFile("monster-green.png");
        }
       else if (square.Name == "Finish")
        {
           LoadImageFromFile("checkered-flag.png");
       }
        else
        {
            // No image needed.
        }

    }

    private void LoadImageFromFile(string fileName) {
        Image image = Image.FromFile(@"Images\" + fileName);
        Image = image;
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;  // Zoom is also ok.
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {

        //  Due to a limitation in WinForms, don't use base.OnPaint(e) here.

        if (Image != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, e.ClipRectangle);

        string name = square.Name;

        // Create rectangle for drawing.
        float textWidth = textFont.Size * name.Length;
        float textHeight = textFont.Height;
        float textX = e.ClipRectangle.Right - textWidth;
        float textY = e.ClipRectangle.Bottom - textHeight;
        RectangleF drawRect = new RectangleF(textX, textY, textWidth, textHeight);

        // When debugging this method, show the drawing-rectangle on the screen.
        //Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        //e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, textX, textY, textWidth, textHeight);

        // Set format of string.
        StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
        drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;  // Right-aligned.

        // Draw string to screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawString(name, textFont, textBrush, drawRect, drawFormat);

        //  Draw player tokens (when any players are on this square).
        const int PLAYER_TOKENS_PER_ROW = 3;
        const int PLAYER_TOKEN_SIZE = 30;  // pixels.
        const int PLAYER_TOKEN_SPACING = (SQUARE_SIZE - (PLAYER_TOKEN_SIZE * PLAYER_TOKENS_PER_ROW)) / (PLAYER_TOKENS_PER_ROW - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < containsPlayers.Length; i++) {
            if (containsPlayers[i]) {
                int xPosition = i % PLAYER_TOKENS_PER_ROW;
                int yPosition = i / PLAYER_TOKENS_PER_ROW;
                int xPixels = xPosition * (PLAYER_TOKEN_SIZE + PLAYER_TOKEN_SPACING);
                int yPixels = yPosition * (PLAYER_TOKEN_SIZE + PLAYER_TOKEN_SPACING);
                Brush playerTokenColour = players[i].PlayerTokenColour;
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(playerTokenColour, xPixels, yPixels, PLAYER_TOKEN_SIZE, PLAYER_TOKEN_SIZE);
            }
        }//endfor
    }

}
}
```

The program trips up at:

```
      else if (square.Name == "Finish")
        {
           LoadImageFromFile("checkered-flag.png");
       }
```

I know it is because of square.name but from going through the code, I cant see why square.Name is not recognizable.

Square is passed from another class using this method

```
private void SetUpGuiGameBoard() 
    {


        for (int i = 0; i <= 55; i++)
        {

            Square q = Board.GetGameBoardSquare(i);
            SquareControl sq = new SquareControl(q, null);

            int coloumn;
            int row;

            if (i == 0)
            {
                BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
            }

            if (i == 55)
            {
                BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
            }

            MapSquareNumToTablePanel(i, out coloumn, out row);

            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(sq, coloumn, row);

        }
```

and Squares are created in this class

```
private static Square[] gameBoard = new Square[56];





    static public void SetUpBoard()
        {
    for (int i = 1; i == 55; i++)
        {


    gameBoard[i] = new Square("Ordinary Square", i);       

        }





        gameBoard[0] = new Square("Start", 0);

        gameBoard[4] = new Square.Lose_Square("Lose Square", 4);
        gameBoard[5] = new Square.Chance_Square("Chance Square", 5);

        gameBoard[9] = new Square.Win_Square("Win Square", 9);

        gameBoard[11] = new Square.Chance_Square("Chance Square", 11);

        gameBoard[14] = new Square.Lose_Square("Lose Square", 14);

        gameBoard[17] = new Square.Chance_Square("Chance Square", 17);

        gameBoard[19] = new Square.Win_Square("Win Square", 19);

        gameBoard[24] = new Square.Lose_Square("Lose Square", 24);

        gameBoard[29] = new Square.Win_Square("Win Square", 29);

        gameBoard[34] = new Square.Lose_Square("Lose Square", 34);
        gameBoard[35] = new Square.Chance_Square("Chance Square", 35);

        gameBoard[39] = new Square.Win_Square("Win Square", 39);

        gameBoard[44] = new Square.Lose_Square("Lose Square", 44);

        gameBoard[47] = new Square.Chance_Square("Chance Square", 47);

        gameBoard[49] = new Square.Win_Square("Win Square", 49);

        gameBoard[53] = new Square.Chance_Square("Chance Square", 53);

        gameBoard[55] = new Square("Finish", 56);

    }



        public static Square GetGameBoardSquare(int n)
        {

            return gameBoard[n];

        }

        public static Square StartSquare()
        {
            return gameBoard[0];
        }

        public static Square NextSquare(int n)
        {

            return gameBoard[(n+1)];
        }
    }
```

Comment: More like square itself is null

Comment: please explain? thanks for reading :)

Comment: I have read that question but It didnt help me solve my specific problem

Comment: In current state of the question there is no way to figure out why `square` is null - so please read the duplicate again and pay attention to debugging recommendations. If you need help after that - please make sure to provide [MCVE] - several pages of code can't be considered "minimal" and small part of large project is not "complete".

Answer (score 0):

The answer already provided is the best way for prevention of any null reference exception. For more clarification I can suggest you to check the call stack at the point the debugger reaches the SquareControl constructor. At this point you should check why the Square object being passed in is a 'NULL'. That will lead you to the root cause of the problem. Hope this helps.